# Looking up tags by amount of followers

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there away to sort the tags on SO by the amount of followers they have? Currently the tags are sorted by the "liveliness" of the tag, and not by the amount of SOers interested in the tag. I think it is an good feature that will allow more important tags to come up for new users.